# Не явившиеся и неуспевающие - в чем разница?

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные, причастия

**Среди не явившихся на заседание** и **число неуспевающих по русскому языку** — почему в этих причастиях НЕ пишется по-разному?

Answer (score 2):

Слово "неуспевающий" характеризует здесь не действие, а приписываемое учащемуся устойчивое **свойство** (слабый ученик и т. п.). Поэтому по функции это *прилагательное*, а не причастие. Поскольку в контексте *нет отрицания* выражаемого им свойства, написание требуется **слитное**. Вариант с отрицанием принципиально возможен, поскольку есть прилагательное с противоположным значением "успевающий" (словарь Ушакова: 2. *успешно занимающийся*):

> На второй год оставляют двоечников, а не успевающих учеников.

Оба слова могут трактоваться и как существительные (употребляться без определяемого "ученик" и т. п.) - с тем же результатом.

Answer (score 1):

"Неуспевающий" в данном случае - прилагательное. Отдельное самостоятельное прилагательно, которое является самостоятельным словом. Поэтому оно пишется слитно.

Answer (score 1):

У Розенталя разбирается этот случай [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#%D0%B7_08)

Я понимаю причину разного написания так.

С одной стороны, варианты  похожи, так как в обоих случаях есть зависимые слова (с ними обычно связывают раздельное написание НЕ) и причастия употреблены в значении существительного.

Но в первом варианте  переход в существительное происходит только в данном предложении, а во втором   слово *неуспевающий* существует как самостоятельное слово (происходит  субстантивация причастия), например: В школе много неуспевающих по разным предметам.

Answer (score 1):

> НЕУСПЕВАЮЩИЙ, -ая, -ее. Имеющий плохую успеваемость, отстающий в занятиях. Н. студент. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9))

Следует отличать от того, кто не успевает что-то сделать вовремя:

> Порой Алиска вдруг круто меняла курс и **не успевающий** затормозить Тишка врезался на полном ходу в угол вольера. [Юлия Друнина. Алиска (1973)]

Answer (score 1):

**Интересно, почему в большинстве ответов не учитывается мнение Розенталя.** Он же разобрал этот пример и фактически ответил на вопрос. ***Неуспевающие*** в данном случае — **существительное (субстантивированное причастие)**, а не прилагательное. Можно было просто указать ссылку на правило.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80

2. Пишется раздельно частица не с полными формами причастия, имеющими при себе пояснительные слова: не возвращённая автору рукопись; не замеченные корректором опечатки; не сданные в срок гранки; не изданные при жизни писателя варианты отдельных глав романа.

   Данное правило распространяется и **на причастия, употребляемые в роли существительных:** В числе не явившихся на заседание были Петров и Сергеев. Но с **субстантивированным причастием (т. е. при перешедшем в разряд существительных)** частица не пишется слитно: В классе много неуспевающих по русскому языку.